# Can't detect Select/Dropdown List Select event on load

Tags: javascript, razor, jquery

Whenever user selects something from a dropdown menu I want to catch the selected item and do something:

```
$("#user-list").live("change", function() {
    var selecteduser = $(this).find(":selected").text();

    ....do something with the selected user
   });
```

Great! This works!
However, sometimes I want to load the page with one of the items already pre-selected as pre-selected list item is passed in as a part of the model:

```
@model RoleUsers

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelecteUserId, Model.Users)
```

The Change event doesn't trigger then unfortunately.

I have a feeling there is a different event out there that I'm missing...

How can I activate my action when a list item is selected on page load, not by a user ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

On document ready, just trigger `change()`

```
$(function() { $("#user-list").change(); });
```

PS, `live()` is deprecated, consider using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Don't use on() if you are using jQuery versions less than 1.7

Comment: I should've mentioned that the list is inside the Jquery modal dialog.
I tried putting what you suggested inside of the dialog() Open: but it doesn't work unfornately